# How to use SlickGrid and DataView to compute totals without grouping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping, slickgrid, dataview

I'm trying to use Slick Grid and DataView to compute column totals like in this example: http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping. However, I don't want to group my rows, so I tried not passing in a getter and formatter to the dataView.setGrouping(..) method, but in my table it shows the grouping row with the text 'undefined'. It does compute my totals correctly. How do I get rid of the unnecessary grouping row?

This is what I'm trying:

```
dataView.setGrouping({
    aggregators: [
        new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum('someField1'),
        new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum('someField2')
    ]
});
```

Comment: Can you put the code of your columns option as well, I might be able to help you after I see it... and also the code that trigger your grouping

Comment: Are you trying to get a total for the complete dataset?

Answer (score 3):

So for the question "How to compute totals without grouping", I know the question is old but since I had to do myself and could not find anything working, I decided to spend some time on it and now I am sharing my solution. The code of SlickGrid will ONLY calculate totals after grouping, that is what Aggregators are for I guess, but I dig the DataView code and came up with a solution, it's a few lines of code but it works great and uses the Slick Aggregators that you already know and that are already defined. I took 2 functions from DataView, some are privates so that is why you need to recopy it in your code too,. So the final code is 1 function name `CalculateTotalByAggregator()` that will call 2 other functions internally. 
Note: pay attention to the `dataview.getItems()`, the `dataview` must be the one coming from your code and might be spelled differently.

```
/** Calculate the total of an existing field from the datagrid 
 * @param object aggregator
 * @return mixed total
 */
function CalculateTotalByAggregator(agg) {
  var constructorName = agg.constructor.name; // get constructor name, ex.: SumAggregator
  var type = constructorName.replace(/aggregator/gi, '').toLowerCase(); // remove the word Aggregator and make it lower case, ex.: SumAggregator -> sum

  var totals = new Slick.GroupTotals();
  var fn = compileAccumulatorLoop(agg);
  fn.call(agg, dataview.getItems());
  agg.storeResult(totals);

  return totals[type][agg.field_];
}

/** This function comes from SlickGrid DataView but was slightly adapted for our usage */
function compileAccumulatorLoop(aggregator) {
  aggregator.init();
  var accumulatorInfo = getFunctionInfo(aggregator.accumulate);
  var fn = new Function(
      "_items",
      " for (var " + accumulatorInfo.params[0] + ", _i=0, _il=_items.length; _i<_il; _i++) {" +
          accumulatorInfo.params[0] + " = _items[_i]; " +
          accumulatorInfo.body +
      "}"
  );
  fn.displayName = "compiledAccumulatorLoop";
  return fn;
}

/** This function comes from Slick DataView, but since it's a private function, you will need to copy it in your own code */
function getFunctionInfo(fn) {
  var fnRegex = /^function[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)\s*{([\s\S]*)}$/;
  var matches = fn.toString().match(fnRegex);
  return {
    params: matches[1].split(","),
    body: matches[2]
  };
}
```

Then on the client side, you only need to call the `CalculateTotalByAggregator(agg)` function and a valid `Slick.Aggregators` object as for example:

```
// use any valid Slick Aggregator object and pass it to the function
var agg = new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("Hours");
var totalHours = gridObject.CalculateTotalByAggregator(agg);

// or on a 1 liner
var totalHours = gridObject.CalculateTotalByAggregator(new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("Hours"));
```

It's a few lines of code, but in this way there is no need of rewriting a function to do sum, another to do average, etc... You simply use the Slick Aggregators that you already use and that's it.. simple :)